# Cannot remove an object from an Array in Angular/Firebase

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried the following function, all values are arriving entering the function but the object is not deleted in the array when I replace the variables with values the object is deleted. What is wrong?

```
  removeMovement(userKey, value: Number , tipo, desc) {
    return this.db.doc(`Users/${userKey}`).update({
      movimentos: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(
        {desc: desc, tipo_movimento: tipo, valor: value}
      ) 
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value was being transformed on a string, so I passed the entirety of the object and then formatted it to a number. The same problem happens with a Date type value and the fix is similar.

```
removeMovement(userKey, movimento: Movimentos) {

    let value = Number(movimento.valor);   

    return this.db.doc(`Users/${userKey}`).update({
      movimentos: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(
        {desc: movimento.desc, tipo_movimento: movimento.tipo_movimento, valor: value })
    });
  }
```